# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Category' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Code:

```
const JoinContent = props => {

const {data} = props;
console.log(data);

return ( <h1>{data.Category}</h1> );

};
```

On Console Log am getting

```
{ 
  Category: "a", 
  Logo: "/static/media/army.a5445eab.svg", 
  Eligibility: "a", 
  Exams: "abc" 
}
```

I have Category in data but on { data.Category } It's throwing an error `Cannot read Property Category of Undefined`

Am working on React and using Hooks, Context.

Comment: How are you passing the 'data' prop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue can be caused if data is loaded asynchronously and it is not present at first render.

You have multiple ways to solve it

1. Initialize `data` to be an empty object if not present in props

```js
const {data = {}} = props;
return (<h1>{data.Category}</h1>);
```

2. Check if `data.Category` is present before rendering

```js
return data?.Category && <h1>{data.Category}</h1>;
```

I prefer the second approach because empty h1 tag will be rendered even if `data.Category` is not present in the first approach

Comment: Yes! It's the good way of avoiding. Can you explain as I want data as compulsory.

Comment: Can you please explain how you are getting the data ?

Comment: Am changing the data in `useLayoutEffect` and then passing through one component as props